# Append/Add Objects without creating a new Parent in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

My Schema be like as follows

```
var DeptSchema   = new Schema({
    name : {type : String, default: ''},
    sku : {type : String, default: ''}, // (SKU = stock keeping unit)
    Product : {
    name : {type : String, default: '', unique:true},
    sku : {type : String, default: '', unique:true}, // (SKU = stock keeping unit)
    description : {type : String, default: '100gm'},
    price : {type : String, default: ''},
    quantity : {type : Number, default: '0'},
    isFav : {type : Boolean, default: 'false'}
    }
});
```

Via Mongoose I've Created an API, but PROBLEM starts when I want to add Products to a specific Dept(Department), A whole new Instance of Department is created instead of the new Product getting appended to the existing Department.
My POST/PUT stated below is

```
.put(function(req, res) {
    // use our Dept model to find the Dept we want
    Dept.findById(req.params.Dept_id, function(err, Dept) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        Dept.name = req.body.name;  // update the Dept info
        Dept.sku = req.body.sku;
        Dept.Product.name = req.body.ProductName;
        Dept.Product.sku = req.body.ProductSKU;
        Dept.Product.description = req.body.ProductDescription;
        Dept.Product.price = req.body.ProductPrice;
        Dept.Product.quantity = req.body.ProductQuantity;
        Dept.Product.isFav = req.body.ProductisFav;            
        // save the Dept
        Dept.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Department updated!' });
        });
    });
})
.post(function(req, res) {

        var dept = new Dept();      // create a new instance of the Dept model
        dept.name = req.body.name;  // set the Dept name (comes from the request)
        dept.sku = req.body.sku;
        dept.Product.name = req.body.ProductName;
        dept.Product.sku = req.body.ProductSKU;
        dept.Product.description = req.body.ProductDescription;
        dept.Product.price = req.body.ProductPrice;
        dept.Product.quality = req.body.ProductQuality;
        dept.Product.isFav = req.body.ProductisFav;
        // save the Dept and check for errors
        dept.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Department created!' });
        });        
    })
```

e.g. We can easily see from the output that Different Fruits instead of appending to the same Fruits Dept. are creating a whole another instance. Also why does ProductSchema not have auto generated Object Id?

```
[
{
"__v": 0,
"_id": "5528027cd4eb13d80cf81f87",
"Product": 
{
"isFav": true,
"quantity": 34,
"price": "128",
"description": "1kg",
"sku": "APL",
"name": "Apple"
},
"sku": "FRT",
"name": "Fruits"
},
{
"_id": "552824abd67bf9d81391ad92",
"__v": 0,
"Product": 
{
"isFav": true,
"quantity": 0,
"price": "40",
"description": "1kg",
"sku": "ORG",
"name": "Orange"
},
"sku": "FRT",
"name": "Fruits"
}
]
```

Thank You for being Patient.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared Product to be an object and not an array.

`Product: {...}` --> `Product: [{...}]`

Also you would need to update your put method to push a new item onto the Dept.Product array rather than updating the properties of Dept. You can read how to properly use subdocs in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

Comment: lets use sub-docs, Product = [ProductSchema] <br> Then how would go about adding a whole new product or amending an existing product within a Department. #thanksforguiding